# React Native: Cannot read property 'RNFSFileTypeRegular' of undefined

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I'm using https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs in my app. But on running I'm getting the following error message.

`Cannot read property 'RNFSFileTypeRegular' of undefined`.

But the same repo cloned and ran in another laptop works fine.

Using Mac OS Sierra.

I suspect this has something to do with `node_modules'.

Tried uninstalling node and npm, still the same error. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Did you ever conclude this? Also getting the same error

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
react-native link react-native-fs
```

Comment: In Windows UWP , i got this issue.. can any one know how to resolve this?..

Comment: This won't work anymore because "link" is deprecated now.

Comment: @TanmayAgarwal Have you figured it out? What's the solution?

Answer (score 2):

- Use manual linking instead of automatic linking
- Then remove cache using the following command

  react-native start --reset-cache
- Then re-run `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`

This should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try Xcode for RUN the Project it Fixed my Issue on IOS.